# how to display images with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image

I'm trying to upload images to my website but it does not show up[image: Here is the result whe displaying the image]

this is the HTML

```
<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="post-image">
    <canvas style="display: none" id="canvas-preview" style="overflow:hidden;"></canvas>
    <img id="img-preview" src="{{ url('backend/'). ($posts->preview_image?'/'. $posts->preview_image:'/post_preview/post-image.png')}}"> </div>
    <div class="m-b-10">
        <a id="upload-submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-sm" onclick="file.click();"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload Picture </a>
         {{  Form::file('preview_image', ['class'=> 'btn btn-warning btn-block btn-sm','id'=>'file','style'=>'visibility:hidden']) }}
  </div>
  </div>
```

the controller:

```
public function create()
    {        $this->authorize('create', Post::class);

        return \View::make('posts.edit')
            ->with('posts', new \App\Models\Post);
    }
```

and the model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    const DEFAULT_PREVIEW_IMAGE = "post_preview/post-image.png";

    /**
     * get preview image
     * @return mixed|string
     */
    public function getPreviewImage()
    {
        return $this->show_preview_image?$this->preview_image:static::DEFAULT_PREVIEW_IMAGE;
        //return $this->preview_image;
    }
}
```

I tried to add multiple extensions like `jpg`, `jpeg` or `gif` in the model but the problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For laravel images should be stored in storage folder or you can create a folder inside storage folder. You also need to create symbolic link

```
 php artisan storage:link
```

Here is how to upload the file to the storage folder

```
if ($request->hasFile('file_name')) {
                $file = $request->file('file_name');
                $fileName = str_replace(' ', '-', $file->getClientOriginalName());
                $uploadPath = storage_path('app/public/folder_name');
                $path = $request->file('file_name')->move($uploadPath, $fileName);
                $uploadPathFile = $fileName;
            }
```

Then you save the path to your DB.
For showing the image in the blade

```
<img src="/storage/folder_name/{{$data->image}}" alt="No image available" class="img-thumbnail">
```

Here $data->image is only the path

Comment: is the condition in the upload () method? I'm trying to add animage from summernote. The image is added to the specified folder but it can not be found on the server and I get this error: ``The requested URL /backend/imagesummernote/jlgRjT0uFzlZnRR9gSfO1igMRC4VApYPlNt7g5tJ.png was not found on this server``

Comment: Are you storing the image in public or storage folder ?

Comment: i'm storing in the storage folder

Comment: Are you storing image name of image path in DB. Also have you created any folder in storage folder for storing images

Answer (score 0):

is your image stored in a public directory - try accessing the URL in your browser to see if the response is the expected image.
If not please provide more details how are you trying to retrieve the image (via binary response or stored as a public asset)?

Comment: @Dipply the image is stored in the public folder. I noticed that the added images are saved in the folder but can not be found on the server.